# Повторный ввод логина и пароля при запуске приложения. Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

В моем тестовом приложении настроена аутентификация через фильтры. При первом запуске программы, нужно вводить дважды логин и пароль, потому что с первого раза не может авторизовать, выводит ошибку о неверных логине/пароле. Вот мой метод `post` из AuthServlet :

```
 @Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String login = req.getParameter("login");
    String password = req.getParameter("password");
    if (login.equals("admin") && password.equals("admin")) {
        HttpSession admSession = req.getSession();
        admSession.setAttribute("login", "admin");
        req.setAttribute("role", Role.ADMIN);
        resp.sendRedirect(String.format("%s/users", req.getContextPath()));

    } else {
        if (ValidateService.getInstance().isValidLogPass(login, password)) {
            HttpSession session = req.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("login", login);

            User user = DBStore.getInstance().findByLogin(login);
            session.setAttribute("role", user.getRole());
            session.setAttribute("user", user);
            resp.sendRedirect(String.format("%s/users", req.getContextPath()));
        } else {
            req.setAttribute("error", "Invalid credentials");
            doGet(req, resp);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Какокие логин и пароль вы вводите?

Comment: Если ввожу admin/admin то захожу с первого раза, но надо обновить страницу чтобы увидеть список юзеров(по задаче, после авторизации, попадаю на страницу с таблицей юзеров). А если ввести логин и пароль из существующих в базе юзеров, то надо дважды вводить, потому что с первого раза пишет что данные неверные.

Comment: А вы можете вывести список пользователей без авторизации?

Comment: нет, для любой операции нужно сначала авторизоваться. Редиректит на страницу авторизации при попытке попасть в другое место.